# pathForResource dynamic input

Tags: iphone

I am trying to write code with dynamic input for pathForResource but I get null value for the directory listing. the files I am using are wav files. Here is the code. I have a.wav file in the project folder. What is wrong here? how can I make this work? Please help.

```
int alphanum = 97;

NSString *alphastring = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",alphanum];
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:alphastring ofType:@"wav"];

AVAudioPlayer *theplayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path] error:NULL];

[theplayer play];
```